# C++ pointer to member function, declaration

Tags: c++, declaration, pointer-to-member

I have the following class:

```
class Point2D
{
protected:

        double x;
        double y;
public:
        double getX() const {return this->x;}
        double getY() const {return this->y;}
...
 };
```

and pointer to the member function declared in another class:

```
double ( Point2D :: *getCoord) () const;
```

How to declare/initlialize pointer to the member function for:

*1] static class member function*

```
Process.h

class Process
{
   private:
      static double ( Point2D :: *getCoord) () const; //How to initialize in Process.cpp?
      ...
};
```

*2] non class member function*

```
Process.h

double ( Point2D :: *getCoord) () const; //Linker error, how do declare?

class Process
{
   private:
      ...
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The only thing you haven't done is to qualify the name of the function with the class name that it is a member of. Instead of providing a definition of `Process::getCoord` you've declared a global pointer-to-member called `getCoord`.

```
double ( Point2D::* Process::getCoord ) () const;
```

You can provide an initializer:

```
double ( Point2D::* Process::getCoord ) () const = &Point2D::getX;
```

Comment: Thanks, I wrote it in reversed order: double ( Process::Point2D::* getCoord ) () const = &Point2D::getX;

Answer (score 1):

According to the [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.5) it's best to use `typedef`:

```
typedef double (Point2D::*Point2DMemFn)() const;

class Process
{
      static Point2DMemFn getCoord;
      ...
};
```

Initialization:

```
Process::getCoord = &Point2D::getX;
```

Comment: `Process::getCoord = &Point2D::getX;` is not a valid definition (or declaration) as there is no type, it's just an assignment expression so not valid where you have it. Was it supposed to be a definition?

Comment: The question was how to declare/initialize pointer getCoord. I wrote first how to declare it, and then how to initialize it.

Comment: You've changed the declaration, but I don't see a definition (the lack of which was probably the cause of the link error in the question) or an initialization (assignment isn't the same as initialization), perhaps I don't understand what you're trying to show?

Comment: I tried to answer the question. If OP is not satisfied with the answer he can ask for clarifications.

Comment: Sorry, I'm obviously not making myself clear. I'm just trying to help make this a better answer. The thing that you've labelled "Initialization:" is just an assignment. If that's what your intention was then you should probably make it clear that it needs to be in a function. e.g. `void init() { Process::getCoord = &Point2D::getX; }` .  The asker will still need a definition of this static member somewhere outside of a function or class definition (e.g. `Point2DMemFn Process::getCoord;`) and he could provide an initializer as well (e.g. `Point2DMemFn Process::getCoord = &Point2D::getX;`)

Comment: Ah, I get it, last line could be interpreted as bad answer if the question was definition with initialization, however the answer is really assignment. The thing is, I read OP's mind and figured out that he wanted assignment instead of initialization, so I just answered the question in his mind, not what he wrote ;-)